# Remove category path/catelog path from product URL in magento

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting

I am new in Magento I have the problem in my website

How can I remove www.websiteurl.com/catalog/category/view/s/large-beverage-glasses/id/61/

to www.websiteurl.com/glasses/large-beverage-glass/

where glasses in main category and large-beverage-glass in sub category

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by going to :

> Admin - System – Configuration – Catalog – Catalog - Search Engine Optimisations – selecting **No** in *Use Categories Path for Product URLs*

[Use Categories Path for Product URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVlaQ.png)

Click Save Config

With this option enabled, the product URL will also include the category URL Keys. While it could be argued this causes duplicate content, product pages might also benefit from this because they become part of a bigger structure.

If not change, try to Re-Index the Catalog URL Rewrites